# Is it possible to copy macros using VBA code across Access databases?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have an Access macro which uses RunCode action to execute a VBA function. Is there a way to copy this macro across multiple databases while keeping the VBA code attached to it somehow? Or does the VBA code need to be manually copied into each new database?

Comment: you could just linnk via references

Comment: Hi @DougCoats could you clarify what you mean? I'm not super familiar with VBA.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/access/concepts/settings/set-a-reference-to-a-visual-basic-project-in-another-microsoft-access-database-o